# How to create a wildcard search function using MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wildcard

Currently I'm editng some PHP/Javascript codes for a database website that uses MySQL to store it's data. As of now, if I search for something in an input data line entry box, the search results pulled from MySQL will show up. However, I'd like to input a wildcard function, such that if I input 'EXAMPLE *' the search results will pull up data that contain the words EXAMPLE.

The code I'm editing currently uses this to pull up search results from MySQL:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM database.table";

echo $_GET['DATA1'];
if(($_GET['DATA1'] === "") && ($_GET['DATA2'] === "")) {
}
else
{
     $query .= " where 1=1 ";
     $query .= ($_GET['DATA1'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA1A = "'.$_GET['DATA1'].'"';
     $query .= ($_GET['DATA2'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA2A = "'.$_GET['DATA2'].'"';
}

$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
      echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>;
?>
```

I'm not that familiar with PHP, could someone please explain what the above code is doing (specifically the '$query .=' part), and how I could change it so a Wildcard functionality could work? Thank you! (Also, I left out some html code on column headers since they weren't really relevant).

Comment: `'$query .=' part` well  `.=` adds the right hand string to the variable on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code only searches for records that contain the exact word as it uses the comparaison operation  DATA1A = "'.$_GET['DATA1'].'"

to use search you should use the MySQL "LIKE" operation by replacing the lines

```
 $query .= ($_GET['DATA1'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA1A = "'.$_GET['DATA1'].'"';
 $query .= ($_GET['DATA2'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA2A = "'.$_GET['DATA2'].'"';
```

by

```
 $query .= ($_GET['DATA1'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA1A LIKE "%'.$_GET['DATA1'].'%"';
 $query .= ($_GET['DATA2'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA2A LIKE "%'.$_GET['DATA2'].'%"';
```

More information are in the MySQL documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/string-comparison-functions.html

PS: I strongly recommand using prepared Queries with PDO to avoid SQL injection attacks on you website or at least escape some special characters that may cause some problems like ' and %.
I propose you use this code instead:

```
<?php
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db_name, $user, $pass, $pdo_options);
$param=array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM database.table";

echo $_GET['DATA1'];
if(($_GET['DATA1'] === "") && ($_GET['DATA2'] === "")) {
}
else
{
     $query .= " where 1=1 ";
     $query .= ($_GET['DATA1'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA1A LIKE ?';
     if($_GET['DATA1'] != "") array_push($param,"%".$_GET['DATA1']."%");
     $query .= ($_GET['DATA2'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA2A LIKE ?';
     if($_GET['DATA2'] != "") array_push($param,"%".$_GET['DATA2']."%");
}

$req = $bdd->prepare($query);
$req->execute($param);
while ($row=$req->fetch())
{
      echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['DATA1A']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['DATA2A']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

I didn't try this out but it should work

Answer (score 0):

The code will append `where 1=1` to $query if $_GET['DATA1'] or $_GET['DATA2'] is not empty. Then it will append `and DATA1A = "XXX"` if $_GET['DATA1'] is not empty. (where XXX is the content of $_GET['DATA1']). Same for $_GET['DATA2'].

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the LIKE function in MySQL to have wildcards

```
 $query .= " where 1=1 ";
 $query .= ($_GET['DATA1'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA1A LIKE "%'.$_GET['DATA1'].'%"';
 $query .= ($_GET['DATA2'] === "") ? '' : ' and DATA2A LIKE "%'.$_GET['DATA2'].'%"';
```